# How to iterate over all combinations of two function arguments and return an 'n by m' matrix in r

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

I want to count the number of first, second, third etc. preferences that a candidate has received in a (randomly generated) election:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

set.seed(42)

results <- replicate(10, sample.int(5,5)) %>%
 t() %>%
 tbl_df() %>%
 set_colnames(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
     A     B     C     D     E
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     5     4     1     2     3
 2     3     5     1     2     4
 3     3     5     4     1     2
 4     5     4     1     3     2
 5     5     1     3     2     4
 6     3     2     5     1     4
 7     4     5     2     3     1
 8     5     1     4     2     3
 9     2     5     1     4     3
10     5     4     2     3     1
```

My function to do this is:

```
count_prefs <- function(df, candidate, round) {
  df %>%
    filter_at(vars(candidate), all_vars(. == round)) %>%
    nrow()
}
```

The output I want is an 'n by m' table where n is the number of candidates and m is the number of rounds (I realise in this case n = m but I want to solve this issue more generally as well). I tried:

```
map2_dbl(colnames(results), c(1:5), count_prefs, df = results)
```

but it returns

```
[1] 0 1 1 1 0
```

which is only 'A 1' 'B 2' 'C 3' 'D 4' 'E 5'.

The solution I have so far is to use cross2() to get a list of all the combinations and apply an adjusted version of the same function:

```
count_prefs2 <- function(df, cand_round) {
  df %>%
    filter_at(vars(cand_round[[1]]), all_vars(. == cand_round[[2]])) %>%
    nrow()
}

map_int(cross2(colnames(results), c(1:5)), count_prefs2, df = results)

[1] 0 2 4 2 2 1 1 2 4 2 3 0 1 3 3 1 3 2 1 3 5 4 1 0 0
```

This gives me the right numbers but I then need to convert this into a matrix and then a data frame to get the result I want

```
map_int(cross2(colnames(results), c(1:5)), count_prefs2, df = results) %>%
  matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE) %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  set_colnames(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
      A     B     C     D     E
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     0     2     4     2     2
2     1     1     2     4     2
3     3     0     1     3     3
4     1     3     2     1     3
5     5     4     1     0     0
```

Is there a more elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: A tidyverse way is `gather(results) %>% count(value, key) %>% spread(key, n, fill = 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shorter base R option is using `stack` as mentioned by @markus

```
table(stack(df))
```

---

A base R method using `sapply` is to count the frequency of each column using `table` specifying the `levels` based on maximum value a column can take (column number in the dataframe).

```
n <- ncol(df)
sapply(df, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = 1:n)))


#  A B C D E
#1 0 2 4 2 2
#2 1 1 2 4 2
#3 3 0 1 3 3
#4 1 3 2 1 3
#5 5 4 1 0 0
```

---

Using `purrr` we could do

```
purrr::map_dfr(df,~table(factor(., levels = 1:n)))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
#      A     B     C     D     E
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     0     2     4     2     2
#2     1     1     2     4     2
#3     3     0     1     3     3
#4     1     3     2     1     3
#5     5     4     1     0     0
```

Comment: Another `baseR` option is `table(stack(results))`

Comment: That's a handy function indeed. You might include this option into your answer.

Comment: Thanks all these suggestions are great! I was definitely approaching the problem in a very convoluted way